# Optimizing texture fetches with higher mip levels

Tags: performance, opengl, directx, shader, textures

Let's say I have some shader program in DirectX or OpenGL rendering a full screen quad. And in a pixel/fragment shader I sample some huge textures at random texture coordinates. That is one same texture coordinate for all texture samplings in one shader invocation, but it is various among different shader invocations. These fetch operations produce performance drop, I even think that due to the size of the textures the GPU texture cache is not big enough and is used not efficiently.

Now I have a theoretical question: can I optimize the performance by using some low-resolution like 32x32 *mask* textures, which are built by mipmapping the large textures, and if a value in a mask texture at given texture coordinate at some higher mip level is not appropriate, then I don't need to perform texture fetches at full-size level 0? Something like this in HLSL (GLSL code is pretty similar, but there is no [branch] attribute):

```
float2 tc = calculateTexCoordinates();
bool performHeavyComputations = testValue(largeMipmappedTexture.SampleLevel(sampler, tc, 5));

float result = 0;

[branch]
if (performHeavyComputations)
{
    result += largeMipmappedTexture.SampleLevel(sampler, tc, 0);
}
```

About 50% of texels at mip level 5 will not pass the test. And so a lot of shader invocations should not sample the full-size textures.

But I am introducing branching in the code. May this branching hurt the performance even worse than sampling the full-size texture even if that is not needed? Different GPUs may behave differently, some may not even support branching, will they perform **two** fetches instead of one?

I can test this code on some machines later, but my question is theoretical.

And can you suggest another optimizations, if this won't work properly ?

Comment: Why do you wish to use a mipmap level for this? Is there any logical releationship between the value you pass to `testValue` and the value you would have gotten from proper sampling? Also, are those "50% of texels at mip level 5" in any way spatially coherent?

Comment: Yes, big areas of the large texture dont pass the test and texture samples in these areas may be early discarded if we just look at the higher mip levels. But this requires branching, can it potentially save performance or it may hurt it even worse?

Comment: "*big areas of the large texture dont pass the test*" When I asked about spatial coherency, I meant in terms of *fragments*, not in the space of the texture. You said that the fragment shaders access texels "randomly", so is there any fragment-space coherence to when texels do and do not need to do this?

Comment: No, two neighboring fragments may sample the texture at very different coordinates, so the texture cache suffers. That's why I suggest to sample higher mip levels where texture cache works better for smaller mipped texture size.

Comment: But if there's no coherence in those "higher mip level" accesses, then there will be no coherence in branching behavior.

Comment: That's true. But how bad is it? Is it better to run such early discarding tests with branching, which is bad for GPU, or is it better to perform very random full-size texture readings destroying the texture cache? That's a hard question, and the behaviour may be different on different GPUs...

Comment: I can actually say, that we talk about big reflection texture. And the fragments which sample the reflection texture are the fragments of the sea. So sea waves reflect very random texels of the texture. However we need to perform some extra computations if the reflected texel is not the sky. Which is determined by sampling the reflection depth buffer. The reflection texture is already smaller than the screen size, but it is still big, especially at 4K screens.

Comment: "*So sea waves reflect very random texels of the texture.*" Then why is your reflection texture so big? If there's so little coherency that a user can't make out all of those subtle details, why are they there?

Comment: I told wrong. The reflection color sampling is spatial incoherent, yes. But the depth buffer sampling is spatial coherent. I sample the depth buffer as if the sea is totally flat. That is needed. And for the depth buffer I want to build the mip levels and perform early tests. And some extra computations, if the texel in the depth buffer is not a sky texel. Anyway I can't just use smaller reflection texture.